# Is there an automated way to change the pre-existing copywrite of my source code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The title says it all. I have an Xcode project. I have a pile of Objective-C code. I need to replace/add the copywrite for all the files. Is there an automated way to do this?

Comment: The *copywrite* (not a word) as in the text displayed, or the *copyright* notice at the top of each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple application that targets the existing text in all the files and replaces it with the updated version. 
Depending on the format of the text you could potentially use regex

Comment: This is pretty much what I did for adding IP. Also consider create custom Xcode File Templates with IP.

Comment: Yah. Time to roll up my sleeves and write a shell or perl script.